# Why is Math.pow(16, 6) not equal to parseInt(0xFFFFFF, 10)?

Tags: javascript, css, hex, rgb

I'm dealing with CSS colours and hex encoding. The colour white is expressed in CSS RGB notation as a the hexadecimal #FFFFFF, or 0xFFFFFF in Javascript.

If I understand correctly, each position in a hexadecimal number goes from 0 to 16. So a series of six Fs is equal to 16 * 16 * 16 * 16 * 16 * 16, or 16 to the power of 6: Math.pow(16, 6). The result of this operation is 16777216.

We can also parse hexadecimal values to base 10: parseInt(0xFFFFFF, 10). The result of this operation is 16777215.

Why is there a difference of 1 between the two operations?

Comment: Compare 999 and 10*10*10.

Comment: And why are you trying to parse `0xFFFFFF` in base 10? Did you mean `parseInt("0xFFFFFF", 16)`?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Curiosity, not practical necessity.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I understand that the range [0 to 999] contains 1000 different values. But we have six hex positions, which can start at 0 and go up to 16 each.

Comment: It's the exact same reason, just in a different base.

Comment: `parseInt(0xFFFFFF, 10)` creates the number 16777215, converts it to the string `16777215`, parses it as a base 10 number, to return the number 16777215. It's a silly way of writing `0xFFFFFF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by looking at a decimal number.

999999<sub>10</sub> is not equal to 10<sup>6</sup>.

999999<sub>10</sub> is one less than 10<sup>6</sup>.

999999<sub>10</sub>
= 9 × 10<sup>5</sup>
+ 9 × 10<sup>4</sup>
+ 9 × 10<sup>3</sup>
+ 9 × 10<sup>2</sup>
+ 9 × 10<sup>1</sup>
+ 9 × 10<sup>0</sup>

6 digits can be used to represent 10<sup>6</sup> different numbers: 0 to 999999<sub>10</sub>.

---

Same in hex.

FFFFFF<sub>16</sub> is not equal to 16<sup>6</sup>.

FFFFFF<sub>16</sub> is one less than 16<sup>6</sup>.

FFFFFF<sub>16</sub>
= 15 × 16<sup>5</sup>
+ 15 × 16<sup>4</sup>
+ 15 × 16<sup>3</sup>
+ 15 × 16<sup>2</sup>
+ 15 × 16<sup>1</sup>
+ 15 × 16<sup>0</sup>

6 hex digits can be used to represent 16<sup>6</sup> different numbers: 0 to FFFFFF<sub>16</sub>.

Comment: Yep, figured it out in the meantime with the hints from previous comments/answers. Thanks for your thorough answer though.

Answer (score 0):

In hexadecimal, F = 15, not 16, putting F's adjacently n times will result in 16^n - 1 analogously to putting 9's adjacently n times will result in 10^n -1.

And that's why there's a difference.